# Why does RegionWithin return False in this case?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Is there any mistake here? I expect it returns `True` but the result is `False`.
I have been checking but couldn't find the mistake.

```
 myline = Line[{{-0.9999775897051473`, 1.`}, {-0.9971344923360166`, 
     1.`}, {-0.9837552105989325`, 1.`}, {-0.9703759288618484`, 
     1.`}, {-0.9436173653876803`, 1.`}, {-0.9168588019135122`, 
     1.`}, {-0.8117733541966873`, 1.`}, {-0.7066879064798623`, 
     1.`}, {-0.5106187050385604`, 1.`}, {-0.2980389526916474`, 
     1.`}, {-0.19879992351436487`, 1.`}, {-0.09956089433708235`, 
     1.`}, {-0.05091578283836483`, 1.`}, {-0.0022706713396473052`, 
     1.`}, {-0.00014244771157841357`, 1.`}}];
myregion = 
  Line[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 6}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-5, 6}, {-5, 0}}];
RegionWithin[myregion, myline]
```

[image]

Here is the image showing the line and region.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit (Reply to comment)**

We can use `RegionUnion` and `RegionEqual` to find if a line lies on another lines since if `RegionUnion[A,B]` and `A`  are the same region, then `B` is the subset of `A`.

```
myregion = 
  Line[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 6}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-5, 6}, {-5, 0}}];
line = Line[{.1 {5, 6} + .9 {1, 1}, .2 {5, 6} + .8 {1, 1}}];
Graphics[{{line}, {Red, Opacity[.2], AbsoluteThickness[8], myregion}}]
RegionEqual[RegionUnion[myregion, line], myregion]
```

[image]

**Original**

`RegionWith[reg1,reg2]==True` if and only if `reg1` is contain `reg2`. Sine `myregion` only the boundary of the polygon which does not contain  `myline` as we can see in the picture as below.

```
Graphics[{{myline}, {Opacity[.2], AbsoluteThickness[5], Red, 
   myregion}}]
```

[image]

So we need to construct a close region.

```
Graphics[{{Blue, myline}, {Red, Opacity[.2], AbsoluteThickness[5], 
   Polygon@myregion[[1]]}}]
RegionWithin[Polygon@myregion[[1]], myline]
```

> `True`

[image]

Or

```
RegionWithin[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[myregion]], myline]
```

> `True`

Or

```
Clear[br];
br = BoundaryMeshRegion[myregion[[1]], Line@Range@Length@myregion[[1]]]
RegionWithin[br, myline]
```

> `True`

Comment: Could you explian a bit?
And just an outside question, how would you check if a line is on a boundary of a region or not (a line is part of the regions' boundary)?

Comment: oops, somehow I miss the Polygon.